# In Python 3.5, how are triple quotes (""") considered comments by the IDE?

Tags: python, comments

My CS teacher told me that """ triple quotations are used as comments, yet I learned it as strings with line-breaks and indentations. This got me thinking about - does python **completely** triple quote lines outside of relevant statements?

```
"""is this completely ignored like a comment"""
```

-or, is the computer actually considering this?

Comment: I know that it's used as a multi-line comment, or docstring, which can be inserted at the beginning of a function or class declaration to describe what exactly the function/class does. When used in this way, the interpreter ignores the comment. However, I don't know if it can be used as a string to be stored in a variable or printed by the `print()` function

Comment: @MatthewSchell you actually can. It denotes a string literal, so doing `print("""Hello World!""")` is completely valid.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Triple quoted strings are used as comment by many developers but it is actually not a comment, it is similar to regular strings in python but it allows the string to be in multi-line. You will find no official reference for triple quoted strings to be a comment.

In python, there is only one type of comment that starts with hash `#` and can contain only a single line of text.

According to [PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/), it can however be used as a docstring, which is again not really a comment.

```py
def foo():
    """
    Developer friendly text for describing the purpose of function
    Some test cases used by different unit testing libraries
    """
   <body of the function>
```

You can just assign them to a variable as you do with single quoted strings:

```py
x = """a multi-line text
enclosed by
triple quotes
"""
```

Furthermore, if you try in repl, triple quoted strings get printed, had it really been a comment, should it have been printed?:

```py
>>> #comment
>>> """triple quoted"""
'triple quoted'
```

Answer (score 3):

As someone else already pointed out, they are indeed strings and not comments in Python. I just wanted to add a little more context about your question of "is the computer actually considering it?"

The answer is yes, since it isn't a comment. Take the below code for example:

```
def my_func():
"""
Some string
"""
    print("Hello World!")
my_func()
```

Trying to run this will actually produce a syntax error because of the indentation.